# Selecting image inside SVG tag in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, svg

I have just started working in selenium and stuck at a point and need help.
Here is my html. I am using python selinium

```
<div id="d3_tree">
  <svg>
    <g>
      <g class="node vm node_pe">
        <image class="mainNode" xlink:href="images/edge.png"> </image>
        <image xlink:href="images/gate.png"></image>
      </g>
      <g class="node vm node_pe">
        <image class="mainNode" xlink:href="images/edge.png"> </image>
        <image xlink:href="images/gate.png"></image>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

i want to get the image tag of all vm node_pe so i can check which node has image.

These are the xpaths i tried using, Where i is the loop on xpath.

```
"//div[@id='d3_tree']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='g["+str(i)+"]']/*[name()='image[2]']"
```

Above xpath return NONE

```
"//div[@id='d3_tree']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='g["+str(i)+"]']"
```

Return 1 element but cannot get any attribute.

```
"//*[contains(@class, 'node vm node_pe')]"
```

Return all elements but get_attribute("innerHTML") return NONE

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: `//div[@id='d3_tree']//g[@class = 'node vm node_pe']/image`

Comment: I try by xpath tester and after adding close `</div>` receive `Not well formed: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?image&xlink:href&xlink`

Comment: Forgot to add the </div> but its there in the original code.

Comment: try this:  //div[@id='d3_tree']/g/g[1]/image[1]

Answer (score 1):

This XPATH should work :

```
//*[@id="d3_tree"]/svg/g/g/*[contains(@class, 'mainNode')]/@xlink:href
```

or maybe you can do it like this :

```
images = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#d3_tree image.mainNode'))
for image in images:
    print(image.get_attribute('xlink:href'))
```

to check if a node got image, you can check if attribute is none.

```
if(image.get_attribute('xlink:href') is None):
    print("attribute is none")
```

Comment: second image tag does not have a class attached to it. so it will not get all the images.

Comment: //*[@id="d3_tree"]/svg/g/g/image[2]/@xlink:href gets the second image tag

Comment: or change image css_selector :

images = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#d3_tree image:nth-child(2)'))